# IE pops up a warning box while downloading file from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I am sending pdf data  as a file from server using spring mvc , but when it gets to IE it pops up a warning message asking to open or save to local machine. Is there a way   for IE9 not  to show this pop up box and directly opens file with acrobat, without user action?

Answer (score 0):

No! You can't download a file to the client's computer without their consent. Well, you can, but to an special folder controlled by the browser and inaccesible to other applications. If you could do what you suggest, anyone could send a virus to your computer!

The only thing you can do is configure the browser to open the PDF file inside it, in an iframe, or in another tab ... But you can't do that with code, obviously. Each user has to do it.